# iCloud key-value storage in WatchKit Extension

Tags: ios, icloud, watchkit

I have an app that is syncing settings with iCloud key-value storage. This is working great between iOS device and with both the app and Today Extension but in the WatchKit extension the NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore doesn't have any of the values set in the app.

In the Capabilities tab the app and both extensions have iCloud turned on, key-value storage checked, app groups turned on and the same group selected. I have checked the entitlements files for both extensions and they are identical.

Am I missing something?

**Update**

I got it working but I am not sure what I did that fixed it.

Comment: That all sounds right. Could you provide some more info around `WatchKit extension isn't working`?

Comment: Updated the questions. The NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore doesn't contain any of the values set in the app.